# Функция которая удаляет дефисы между словами

Tags: javascript

```js
function camelize(str){
  var d = str.split('-');
  var h = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
    var s = d[i];
    var f = s.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var r = s.slice(1);
    var t = f + r;
    h.push(t)
     console.log(h);
  }
 var v = h.join('')
 console.log(v);
}

console.log(camelize("my-short-string"))
```

Напишите функцию camelize(str), которая преобразует строки вида «my-short-string» в «myShortString».

**Хочу узнать можно как-нибудь лучше код написать или нет ?**

Comment: У Вас получился не camelCase, а PascalCase, так как первое слово заглавное, что бы исправить нужно цикл запускать с 1, а не с 0.
+ можно отказаться от дополнительного массива h, мутируя начальный массив в цикле по индексу.

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil  спасибо я и не заметил

Comment: А ещё ваша функция ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
function camelize(str){
  return str.split('-')
            .map((w, i) => i ? (w = w.split(''), w.shift().toUpperCase() + w.join('')) : w)
            .join('')
}

console.log(camelize("my-short-string"))
```

---

Вариант с первой заглавной:

```js
function camelize(str) {
  return str.split('-')
            .map(w => (w = w.split(''), w.shift().toUpperCase() + w.join('')))
            .join('')
}

console.log(camelize("my-short-string"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Моя версия однострочника, раз уж у нас тут парад однострочников

```
function camelize(str) {
    return str.replace(/-(\w)/g, (_, c) => c.toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так сделал:

```
function camelize(str) {
    let arr = str.split('-');
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        arr[arr.indexOf(item)] = item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1, item.length);
    });
    str = arr.join('');
    return str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.slice(1, str.length);
}

console.log(camelize('my-short-string')); // "myShortString"
```

Comment: Тоже получился PascalCase )

Comment: @SultanovShamil Я обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
function camelize(str){
  return str.split('-').map((el,i) => i !== 0 ? el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1) : el).join('')
}
```